# Python OpenCV video doesnt play - Raspberry

Tags: python

When i run program, i see this error and video doesnt play
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/My_Files/LaneDetection.py", line 9, in 
img = cv2.resize(img,(480,240))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')
        while True:
            success, img = cap.read() 
            img = cv2.resize(img,(480,240))
            cv2.imshow('Vid',img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
```

and i changed code. I doesnt see any error but video doesnt play

```
 import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
        if __name__ == '__main__':
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')
        while True:
            success, img = cap.read() 
            try:
                img = cv2.resize(img,(480,240))
            except:
               
                cv2.imshow('Vid',img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `while(cap.isOpened()):` instead of `while(True):`  ?

Comment: yes i have. But it doesnt play.

Comment: The `indentation` of your code seems incorrect. why have you placed `cv2.imshow('Vid',img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)` inside except block? It should be outside except block

Comment: I tried it on my computer.It work normal but i tried on raspberry pi, it doesnt play.I wrote print but i didnt see anything.

Comment: Check the below code and see whether you see `Exception occurred`. If so give the error message.

Comment: No i didnt see.I think this problem is with raspberry pi.

Comment: You tell it to only show the frame, if an exception occurred during resizing. I don't think that's your intention, is it?